# Hide full path to project in Project browser?

Tags: macos, jetbrains-ide, appcode

Trying out AppCode (2.5.4) at the moment I'm rather annoyed by having the **full paths** to projects always showing up in the '*Project*' view.

[image]

Browsing the prefs I cannot find a way to turn this off?
I'd rather prefer the Xcode way of having just the project's name..

In particular working with workspaces and sub-projects a lot it adds a lot of visual clutter.

Comment: AppCode is a development tool and thus on topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable this path at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It adds visual clutter to the UI. I'm frequently working with workspaces containing up to a dozen projects and everything that distracts me from the content tends to annoy..  It would be great to have an option for not showing the path (similar to how Xcode does it)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not am Apple expert. Under Linux, however, you could, as a workaround, create a soft link using "ln" to reference the long folder path from your home dir in a short fashion and use that path in your app. Maybe that works under Apple's system as well?

Comment: Sorry, but that's purely an app-level question. No need to screw up the structure on your hard drive, is there?

Comment: You're not screwing anything up by creating soft links, and if the app doesn't support it I think it's a simple and easy way to achieve what you want.