# Hide Full Path Next to Project in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I've been using IntelliJ, and I'm kind of annoyed by the full path being displayed next to the project name in the project view. I am aware that this question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215486/hide-full-path-to-project-in-project-browser). However, it is two years old and for AppCode, and I was wondering if IntelliJ has been updated to allow disabling this.

[image: capture]

Comment: Check this topic, it might be helpful: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206175079-Is-there-any-way-to-display-the-full-path-of-the-file-in-IntelliJ-s-menu-bar-

Comment: @DimaSan thanks for the suggestion, but that wasn't quite what I was looking for - I want to know how to **hide** the full path next to the **project**, not **show** the full path for a **file**.

Comment: it is 2023 now, any news here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

<s>There is no such setting.</s>

<s>https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126014 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.</s>

---

**UPDATE (2018-05-24):**

Since 2018.1 version it's now possible to hide such a path by using special/internal option ( [check this comment for details](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126014#comment=27-2734975) ).

For this you need to perform the following steps:

- Use `Main Menu | Help | Edit Custom Properties...` inside the IDE
- Agree to create a file if it does not exist
- Insert the option without leading `-D` part (just put `project.tree.structure.show.url=false` on an empty line)
- Save the file
- Restart your IDE to see the changes

**Alternatively** you can do the same via internal Registry (this way was added a version or two later):

- `Help | Find Action...` (or `Search Everywhere`, `Actions` tab -- the same thing)
- Type `registry` there
- Locate and invoke `Registry...` entry
- Inside the Registry window locate that `project.tree.structure.show.url` entry (just start typing) and make sure it is disabled/unticked
- Save the changes
- Restart your IDE to see the changes

I'm using this and it works just fine for me since 2018.x (PhpStorm user here).

Comment: Worked for me only after "Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Comment: How about version control view? Do you know if hiding full path in version control is possible?

Comment: I tried `versioncontrol.tree.structure.show.url=false` (also things like `vcs.tree`, `version.control.tree` etc) but did not work!

Comment: @CrazyCoder is it possible?

Comment: This worked for "Project", but how to make it work for "scopes" ?

Comment: Worked for me just on restart. Thanks

Comment: `-D` was required for me, IJ was crashing without it. IJ 2019.3.4  this worked for me `-Dproject.tree.structure.show.url=false`

Comment: I've tested it on IJ 2021.1 and it worked without the `-D` flag!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40909474/8431247) there is no such setting. However the reference plugin ([Path Hide](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8378-path-hide)) doesn't seem to work with Intellij Ultimate 2017.3

Thus I believe that currently there is not solution to this problem and the relevant ticket in [IDEA-126014](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126014) is still in development

Comment: This worked for me on Intellij Ultimate as well.

However I just tried it with Intellij Community Edition (2018.1) and it does NOT work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that on latest versions (I'm using the 2023.2.4) of IntelliJ as follows. Open the IDEA with no project, and click on the button at the left and bottom, then click on Edit Custom Properties, and past the following line:

```
project.tree.structure.show.url=false
```

Click save, then quite completely IntelliJ, and reopen it. Like below:

[image]