# Display only relative path to project folder

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I turn off the display of this full path to the folder, so that only the current directory where you are is shown?

[image]

I couldn't find this option in WebStorm and can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/40909474/783119 -- does it resolve your issue? (works fine for me)